# Parse Cloud Code development and production version control

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, version-control, parse-cloud-code, staging

I have a Parse application that will soon be used in production, and I need to be able to continue developing things locally without breaking things for live users when I make changes to cloud code.

I have cloned the app, and can now deploy to either the production or staging app using the `parse deploy staging` and `parse deploy production` commands, however these commands only work if I am on the master branch.

What I would like to have are two branches in git, one that can be pushed to my staging app, and the other that can be pushed to the production app.

At the moment all I can think of doing is to just tag commits in master as being pushed to production, then continue ontop of that for development, but that is going to be a nightmare if I need to patch the released app when I have all my development changes on master.

Pushing directly to the heroku git repos doesn't seem to work either, parse deploy must be doing something extra (plus it tries to build the app so I can see when things go wrong).

Another issue is that when other developers start working on this as well, we won't be able to all deploy to the development server, and as far as I know there isn't an easy way to run parse cloud code locally on windows.

What is the best way to manage all this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) (use [parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example)), [parse-dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) and [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#production) on a local or remote development server. You and your team can now develop everything locally, test and then deploy to production.

Comment: If I do go to the effort of setting up a local parse server, there still remains the problem that I can't deploy a branch that isn't master, which means I have no way to keep the development and production versions separate.

How would I go about having a development branch that is deployed to one server (for example my local server), and have master deploy to the online production server?

Comment: Okay, I have partially answered my own question here.

I can actually push directly to heroku and have it work, I just wasn't pushing to master on heroku (I assumed a branch would automatically push to the one that it is tracking, but sourcetree had other plans).

I am still not sure how I go about deploying this code locally since I am using heroku. Or do I just have to use cloud code on my local parse server and hope it works when I go to heroku in production?